# Sending mail in bash script outputs literal \n instead of a new line

Tags: linux, bash, email, sendmail

I am using the following bash script to send an email

```
 #!/bin/bash

 recipients="me@web.com, you@web.com"
 subject="Just a Test"
 from="test@test.com"

 message_txt="This is just a test.\n Goodbye!"

 /usr/sbin/sendmail "$recipients" << EOF
 subject:$subject
 from:$from
 $message_txt
 EOF
```

But when the email arrives the $message_txt content is printed literally like this :

```
 This is just a test.\n Goodbye!
```

Instead of interpreting the new line like this :

```
 This is just a test.
 Goodbye!
```

I've tried using :

```
 echo $message_txt
 echo -e $message_txt
 printf $message_txt
```

But the result is always the same. Where am I going wrong?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `message_txt=$(echo -e 'this is just a test.\nGoodbye!')`

Comment: Also you should separate message headers from body whith an empty line

Comment: Thanks, this worked ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash you should use following syntax

`message_txt=$'This is just a test.\n Goodbye!'`

Single quotes preceded by a `$` is a new syntax that allows to insert escape sequences in strings.

Check following [documentation](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) about the quotation mechanism of `bash` for ANSI C-like escape sequences

Answer (score 2):

You can also embed newlines directly in a string, without an escape sequence.

```
message_txt="This is just a test.
Goodbye!"
```

Comment: You know I didn't even think to try that!