# Sendmail bash script, concatenate strings with new line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sendmail

I am concatenating `xmsg` and `links` to new variable `body`. 
What I am trying to accomplish is when email send out. I want new line between `xmsg` and `links

```
xmail="sendmail"

links="<a href="https://www.xxx>Unsubscribe</a>"
xmsg='Hello World'
body=$xmsg \n $links

### Compose emails one at a time, per loop.
"$xmail" "$email" << EOF
subject:$xsub
from:$xfrom
Content-Type: text/html;
Mime-version:1.0;
$body
EOF
```

Excepted output in email

```
Hello World
Unsubscribe
```

I tried almost everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779781/sending-mail-in-bash-script-outputs-literal-n-instead-of-a-new-line). But none works, either I get blank body in email or all in same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending an HTML email and need to use `<br>` instead of `\n`.

You need to enclose the whole string in double quotes. Try `body="$xmsg <br> $links"`